# jump between the ViewControllers which the navigation bar is hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have a problem about the navigation bar.

I have `ViewControllerA` with a hidden `NavigationBar`. I have set the `navigationBar` hidden using the code below:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

I push `ViewControllerA` and then `ViewControllerA` again. But `NavigationBar` will appear when I go back to First `ViewControllerA` by using system gesture.

I hope I can get some ways to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, can you please rephrase your question? I am entirely sure what do you want to ask?

Comment: I'm  sorry for my grammar,There are someone help me rephrase the question. @PavelGatilov

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, hide it in ViewControllerA and then show it in ViewControllerB, don't show it when ViewControllerA will disappear. The below code is all you need, good luck.

ViewControllerA:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

ViewControllerB:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Dear First You are set Navigation bar hidden at Navigation Controller Property (Storyboard->Click Navigation Controller->Property) and You want Navigation Bar in any View Controller Scene so your are add this code in .m file of view controller.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

}